# Conversion to cell from double is not possible - MATLAB

Tags: excel, matlab

Is there a way of reading a text file to a cell array of strings and write it into excel file ?

i try something like this :

```
for d = 1:n
dFile(d,1) = d
content = strcat(dirpathstr{d})
filecontent =textscan(content, '%s', 'whitespace', '')
dFile(d,2) = filecontent
end
```

but it give me error "Conversion to cell from double is not possible", then i improve it with

```
"dFile(d,2) = str2double (filecontent)"
```

but its give me 'NaN' as result,

can anyone help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `dFile` is a double array, i.e. it only contains numbers. The first column always contains `d`, which is a number - that's fine.

The `textscan` function however returns a *cell* array. With the line

```
dFile(d,2) = filecontent
```

you try to take the cell array and save it inside the double array. This is not possible, as they are different data types. That is exactly what MATLAB tells you:

> Conversion to cell from double is not possible

In your case, you don't need `dFile` to be a double array, you can just make it a cell array too. Then you can assign `filecontent` to `dFile`, as they are of the same data type.

```
for d = 1:n
    dFile{d,1} = d
    content = strcat(dirpathstr{d})
    filecontent =textscan(content, '%s', 'whitespace', '')
    dFile{d,2} = filecontent
end
```

Comment: thank you @hbaderts, but when i open the excel file its all give me empty result ... only the header file are remain there... :( any suggestion ?

Comment: @milkyway can you manually look at the cell array `dFile` and verify that the data in this cell array is correct? If `dFile` contains the correct data, the problem is how you write the new excel file.